# git thinks my Macbook pro is a Galaxy-S9 in the terminal

Tags: git, terminal

See photo below.
I don't use a Galaxy-S9 nor do I know anyone who does...
Anyone know how this could have happened?

[image]

Comment: git does not have a terminal. Nor does git have tabs like that. That looks to be VS Code.

Comment: The host name can come from the DHCP server that's giving you your IP address. Are you connected to a network you don't usually connect to?

Comment: @chepner Yea! I *was* connected to an Airbnb network.

Comment: @crashmstr Ah, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is Visual Studio Terminal which is very similar to Ubuntu Terminal.
Basically, the syntax for the prefix in the terminal is:
`USERNAME@DEVICE_NAME$`
For example, mine is like this(where username is `anupam` and device name is `g3`):

```
anupam@g3:~$
```

So, you can edit these two parameters in your system and it will start showing you these parameters in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You named your computer  "Galaxy-S9". You can change that in the settings of computer

Comment: More likely, a DHCP server named it for them.